# awk append column from another file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a csv file containing following data:

```
xyz/randomname-12ab-ab12-234234asdasd,1233.sdfsdf-sdfsdf,123123,10:10.0
abc/randomname-34ab-cd34-456456dfgdfg,4545,321321,10:10.0
```

I'm running following for loop:

```
for x in $(cat csv_file | awk -F ',' '{print $1}'); do
    aws s3 ls s3://bucket/$x --human-readable --profile default | awk '{print $3" "$4" "$5}'
done
```

which gives me an output like:

```
12.2 MiB randomname-12ab-ab12-234234asdasd

30.1 MiB randomname-34ab-cd34-456456dfgdfg
```

What I'd like to achieve is to append second column from the csv file plus leading characters from the first column to get output like:

```
12.2 MiB randomname-12ab-ab12-234234asdasd 1233.sdfsdf-sdfsdf.xyz

30.1 MiB randomname-34ab-cd34-456456dfgdfg 4545.abc
```

edit:
`aws s3 ls s3://bucket/ --human-readable --profile default`
output:

`PRE xyz/`

`PRE abc/`

`2019-03-28 11:16:59  10.5 MiB randomname-1234`

`2019-01-14 11:53:47  90.2 MiB randomname-3456`

`randomname-12ab-ab12-234234asdasd`
and
`randomname-34ab-cd34-456456dfgdfg`
files are under xyz and abc folders.

Comment: what's the full output of the `aws s3 ls s3://bucket/$x --human-readable --profile default` ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `for` to read from a file.

This script reads the fields from the csv file in the Bash `while` loop and passes them into AWK variables to be used in the output. The bucket name is split so the last part can be extracted.

```
while read -r bucket second_col
do
    aws s3 ls s3://bucket/$x --human-readable --profile default | awk -v bucket=$bucket -v second_col=$second_col '{split(bucket, bucket_pre, "/"); print $3, $4, $5, second_col "." bucket_pre[2]}'
done <  <(awk -F ',' '{print $1 $2}' csv_file)
```

I didn't know what the second field in the csv file is so I made up a variable name (`second_col`). You should substitute a more meaningful one. It makes it hard to give good answers when dummy data is provided and its meaning can't be discerned and there's no meaning assigned to it in the question.

Comment: That doesn't work either: `x=$(cat source.csv | awk -F ',' '{print $1}')`

`while read -r real-bucket-name second_col`

`> do`

`> aws s3 ls s3://real-bucket-name/$x --human-readable --profile default | awk -v bucket=real-bucket-name -v second_col=$second_col '{split(bucket, bucket_pre, "/"); print $3, $4, $5, second_col "." bucket_pre[2]}'`

`> done <  <(awk -F ',' '{print $1 $2}' source.csv)`

`bash: read: `real-bucket-name': not a valid identifier`

Comment: @SynRomana: Leave off the `x=$()` line completely. My script replaces yours - don't add them together. Variable names can't include hyphens - use underscores instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an all AWK version. I don't have access to AWS so I had to create `bucket/...` tree structure for testing. Let me know if it worked:

```
$ awk -F, '{                                 # separator for csv_file processing
    cmd="ls -h -s bucket/" $1                # form the command, in aws probably:
    # cmd="aws s3 ls s3://bucket/" $1 " --human-readable --profile default"
    cmd | getline ret                        # execute command, get returned output
    close(cmd)                               # close the cmd to save fds
    split($1,tmp,"/")                        # getting the path 
    print ret,$2 "." tmp[1]                  # output
}' csv_file
```

Output with paths and (`touch`ed) files `bucket/abc/randomname-34ab-cd34-456456dfgdfg` and `bucket/xyz/randomname-12ab-ab12-234234asdasd`:

```
0 bucket/xyz/randomname-12ab-ab12-234234asdasd 1233.sdfsdf-sdfsdf.xyz
0 bucket/abc/randomname-34ab-cd34-456456dfgdfg 4545.abc
```

Comment: That gives me: `2018-01-25 16:13:00   12.2 MiB randomname-12ab-ab12-234234asdasd 1233.sdfsdf-sdfsdf.xyz`

`[Errno 32] Broken pipe`
`2018-09-22 06:54:49   30.1 MiB randomname-34ab-cd34-456456dfgdfg 4545.abc`

Comment: That datetime comes off with `split(ret,tmp," ");ret=tmp[3],tmp[4],tmp[5]` after `getline` (untested)  but I can only wonder where that error comes from.

Comment: error comes from `close(cmd)` if I remove it then I'm not getting that error but still displays date. If I use `split(ret,tmp," ");ret=tmp[3],tmp[4],tmp[5]` then I am getting: syntax error on `awk: cmd. line:4:     split(ret,tmp, " ");ret=tmp[3],tmp[4],tmp[5]`

Comment: My bad, that should've been: `split(ret,tmp, " "); ret=tmp[3] OFS tmp[4] OFS tmp[5]`. I'm too excited about the new Raspberry Pi 4 to concentrate properly. :D

Comment: Any idea which awk (and version) you are using?

Comment: re: RPi 4: Me, too!